# R dplyr rolling sum

Tags: r, dplyr

i am implementing a rolling sum calculation through dplyr, but in my database i have a number of variables that have only one or only a few observations, causing an (k is smaller than n) error. i have tried to resolve this in thisj example with filter and merge, but wondering if there is a way to do this more elegantly and automatically within dplyr. please see the example below

```
    #create data
    dg = expand.grid(site = c("Boston","New York"),
                     year = 2000:2004)
    dg$animal="dog"
    dg$animal[10]="cat";dg$animal=as.factor(dg$animal)
    dg$count = rpois(dim(dg)[1], 5)
```

If i would run the code below, because i only have one row with "cat", one gets the (Error: k <= n is not true) error

```
#running average
dg2 = dg %>%
  arrange(site,year,animal) %>%
  group_by(site,animal) %>%
#   filter(animal=="dog") %>%
  mutate(roll_sum = rollsum(x = count, 2, align = "right", fill = NA))
```

i have tried to solve this by using the following code, which filters out the "cat" value and does a subsequent merge, but I was wondering whether one can do this directly inside dplyr, especially as in this solution one would have to specify / know the number of unique rows for each variable in advance and adjust manually if one would change the range of the rolling sum, etc.

```
dg2 = dg %>%
  arrange(site,year,animal) %>%
  group_by(site,animal) %>%
  filter(animal=="dog") %>%
  mutate(roll_sum = rollsum(x = count, 2, align = "right", fill = NA))

merge(dg,dg2,c("site", "year","animal","count"),all.x=TRUE)

       site year animal count roll_sum
1    Boston 2000    dog     5       NA
2    Boston 2001    dog     6       11
3    Boston 2002    dog     6       12
4    Boston 2003    dog     5       11
5    Boston 2004    dog     3        8
6  New York 2000    dog     8       NA
7  New York 2001    dog     3       11
8  New York 2002    dog    12       15
9  New York 2003    dog     3       15
10 New York 2004    cat     3       NA
```

Many thanks - W

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can instead use `RcppRoll::roll_sum` which returns NA if the sample size(`n`) is less than the window size(`k`).

```
set.seed(1)
dg$count = rpois(dim(dg)[1], 5) 
library(RcppRoll)
library(dplyr)
dg %>%
     arrange(site,year,animal) %>%
     group_by(site, animal) %>%
     mutate(roll_sum = roll_sum(count, 2, align = "right", fill = NA))    
#       site year animal count roll_sum
#1    Boston 2000    dog     4       NA
#2    Boston 2001    dog     5        9
#3    Boston 2002    dog     3        8
#4    Boston 2003    dog     9       12
#5    Boston 2004    dog     6       15
#6  New York 2000    dog     4       NA
#7  New York 2001    dog     8       12
#8  New York 2002    dog     8       16
#9  New York 2003    dog     6       14
#10 New York 2004    cat     2       NA
```

Comment: since the specific question asks about a dplyr solution, here is what the the dplyr webpage (dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/window-functions.html) says about rolling functions: "Rolling aggregates operate in a fixed width window. You won’t find them in base R or in dplyr, but there are many implementations in other packages, such as RcppRoll."  There isn't a dplyr function as of now, they recommend Khashaa's solution.

Comment: Best solution I have seen to this so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

roll_Sum from RcppRoll will return an NA in place of an error wherever the number of data points are the less than the window size.

However, in case you want to return the sum of the number of data points present - even if lesser than the window the size, you can use the rollapplyr function from zoo.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

   dg %>%
         arrange(site,year,animal) %>%
         group_by(site, animal) %>%
         mutate(roll_sum = roll_sum(count, 2, align = "right", fill = NA)) %>%
         mutate(rollapply_sum =rollapplyr(count, 2, sum, partial = TRUE) )
```

Rollapply_sum will return the original value or the sum of data points present, even if its less than the window size instead of returning NA.

```
       site  year animal count roll_sum rollapply_sum
     (fctr) (int) (fctr) (int)    (dbl)         (int)
1    Boston  2000    dog     4       NA             4
2    Boston  2001    dog     5        9             9
3    Boston  2002    dog     3        8             8
4    Boston  2003    dog     9       12            12
5    Boston  2004    dog     6       15            15
6  New York  2000    dog     4       NA             4
7  New York  2001    dog     8       12            12
8  New York  2002    dog     8       16            16
9  New York  2003    dog     6       14            14
10 New York  2004    cat     2       NA             2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rollsum is essentially the difference between "two times cumsum" we can write an own version of `roll_sum` in base R.
The function is only two lines long and vectorized, so it should be quite fast.

```
roll_sum <- function(x) {
  y <- cumsum(x)
  y - c(NA_integer_, 0L, head(y, -2L))
}

dg %>%
  arrange(site,year,animal) %>%
  group_by(site, animal) %>%
  mutate(roll_sum = if (n() > 1L) roll_sum(count) else NA_integer_) 

# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   site, animal [3]
   site      year animal count roll_sum
   <fct>    <int> <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Boston    2000 dog        5       NA
 2 Boston    2001 dog        6       11
 3 Boston    2002 dog        3        9
 4 Boston    2003 dog        3        6
 5 Boston    2004 dog        3        6
 6 New York  2000 dog        6       NA
 7 New York  2001 dog        5       11
 8 New York  2002 dog        8       13
 9 New York  2003 dog       12       20
10 New York  2004 cat        3       NA
```

This function can easily be generalized to arbitrary rolling windows `n`:

```
roll_sum <- function(x, n) {
  y <- cumsum(x)
  y - c(rep.int(NA_integer_, n - 1L), 0L, head(y, -n))
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it allows for easy modification of the function to meet distinct criteria that may vary from case to case.