# How to calculate a value on a "cascading" basis in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a `data_frame` that looks like this:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", 
"John Smith", "John Smith"), Account_Number = c("XXXX XXXX 0000", 
"XXXX XXXX 0000", "XXXX XXXX 0000", "XXXX XXXX 0000", "XXXX XXXX 0000"
), Transaction_Date = c("04/01/16", "04/02/16", "04/03/16", "04/04/16", 
"04/05/16"), Amount = c(NA, 749, -256, 392, NA), Balance = c(2000, 
NA, NA, NA, 1500)), .Names = c("Name", "Account_Number", "Transaction_Date", 
"Amount", "Balance"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For ease of viewing in the question, here it is printed:

```
#        Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#       (chr)          (chr)            (chr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
#1 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
#2 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749      NA
#3 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256      NA
#4 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392      NA
#5 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

What I would like to do is fill in the `NA` values in `Balance` with the sum of `Balance[i-1] + Amount[i]`. I thought I could do this easily with `dplyr` using the following:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(mdy(Transaction_Date)) %>%
  mutate(Balance = ifelse(is.na(Balance), as.numeric(lag(Balance)) + as.numeric(Amount), Balance))
```

Unfortunately, that gives me the following:

```
#        Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#       (chr)          (chr)            (chr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
#1 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
#2 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
#3 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256      NA
#4 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392      NA
#5 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

So, it seems that all values are being calculated simultaneously, when what I'd want is for it to go row by row.

The desired outcome would look like this:

```
#        Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#       (chr)          (chr)            (chr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
#1 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
#2 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
#3 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256    2493
#4 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392    2885
#5 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

I believe I could use `apply`, but I'd prefer to keep this in the `dplyr` pipeline if possible. Thanks in advance for any tips.

### Update:

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153835/r-dplyr-rolling-sum), it looks like I could use `RcppRoll::roll_sum`, but that function looks like it only takes one variable whereas I'd need to use two. So I'd also accept an answer that demonstrates how to use that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Edit: Warning!

The original approach presented here will not handle resetting `Balance` properly, as you'll see if you pass it `df %>% bind_rows(df)`. I am only leaving it here as it was the accepted answer. See below for an updated approach that avoids the problem.

---

#### Original [faulty] approach

You're really taking a cumulative sum, but using `cumsum` here is sort of a pain because it doesn't have an `na.rm` argument. However, you can remove and reinsert the `NA` values:

```
# replace NAs with 0s so cumsum will work
df %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)), Balance, Amount) %>% 
    # replace 0 values in Balance with cumsum of Balance and Amount
    mutate(Balance = ifelse(Balance == 0, cumsum(Balance + Amount), Balance)) %>% 
    # put NAs back
    mutate(Amount = ifelse(Amount == 0, NA, Amount))

# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# 
#         Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#        (chr)          (chr)            (chr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
# 2 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
# 3 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256    2493
# 4 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392    2885
# 5 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

Note that if you have actual `0` values in `Balance` or `Amount` (or if that's possible), you may need to make the approach more robust.

---

#### New [functioning] approach

By grouping by the run length of when `Amount` is `NA`, we can make sure we're adding the correct cumulative sum, and not adding `Amount` values before a reset of `Balance`:

```
# pass it a bigger df to test
df %>% bind_rows(df) %>% 
    # replace NAs with last value
    tidyr::fill(Balance) %>% 
    # group so cumsums are not added after Balance reset
    group_by(NA_Amount = is.na(Amount), 
             rle_Amount = data.table::rleid(NA_Amount)) %>%
    mutate(Balance = ifelse(NA_Amount, Balance, Balance + cumsum(Amount))) %>%
    # clean up columns
    ungroup() %>% select(-NA_Amount, -rle_Amount)

# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
# 
#          Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#         (chr)          (chr)            (chr)  (dbl)   (dbl)
# 1  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
# 2  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
# 3  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256    2493
# 4  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392    2885
# 5  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
# 6  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
# 7  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
# 8  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256    2493
# 9  John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392    2885
# 10 John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Balance := c(Balance[1], Balance[1] + cumsum(Amount[-1]))
          , by = cumsum(!is.na(Balance))][]
#         Name Account_Number Transaction_Date Amount Balance
#1: John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/01/16     NA    2000
#2: John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/02/16    749    2749
#3: John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/03/16   -256    2493
#4: John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/04/16    392    2885
#5: John Smith XXXX XXXX 0000         04/05/16     NA    1500
```

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I really need to start learning `data.table`.

Comment: @brittenb you can also translate the above to `dplyr` in a straightforward fashion, though you'll get an extra column from the grouping that you'll need to remove later + will copy the *entire* `data.frame` around a few times instead of the above in-place modification