# Create a new column based multiple rows of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe as this

```
> df<-data.frame(index=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),value=c(2,3,5,8,11,12))
> df
    index value
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     5
4     4     8
5     5    11
6     6    12
```

I want to create a new column which equals to the the sum of three adjacent values of column *value* indexed by column *index*, that is

```
> df_res
  index value res
1     1     2 NA
2     2     3 10
3     3     5 16
4     4     8 24
5     5    11 31
6     6    12 NA
```

The second row of *res* is the sum of (2,3,5), third sum(3,5,8) etc. (the first and last row of *res* do not matter, and I temporarily set it as NA)

How can I get it done in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R dplyr rolling sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153835/r-dplyr-rolling-sum)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,res:=value+shift(value,1)+shift(value,1,type="lead")]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dplyr` and `roll_sum` to do:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(v2 = roll_sum(value, 3,fill = NA))
```

which gives:

```
  index value v2
1     1     2 NA
2     2     3 10
3     3     5 16
4     4     8 24
5     5    11 31
6     6    12 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$res <- sapply(df$index, function(index) 
    ifelse(index > 1 & index < nrow(df),sum(df$value[(index - 1):(index + 1)]), NA))

   index value res
1     1     2  NA
2     2     3  10
3     3     5  16
4     4     8  24
5     5    11  31
6     6    12  NA
```

Comment: Hi, I wonder why df$res <- sapply(df$index, function(index) (sum(df$value[index - 1:index+1]))) does not give the same result? The thing is that I want to simplify the addition of the three df$value items, because I have more than 3 items.

Comment: @DingLi It should, compare `2-1:4-2` vs `(2-1):(4-2)`

Comment: I've edited the code to make it a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Using head and tail:

```
df$res <- df$value + c(tail(df$value, -1), NA) + c(NA, head(df$value, -1))

df
#   index value res
# 1     1     2  NA
# 2     2     3  10
# 3     3     5  16
# 4     4     8  24
# 5     5    11  31
# 6     6    12  NA
```

Or using zoo:

```
df$res <- zoo::rollsum(df$value, 3, na.pad = TRUE)
```